browser_cookie3 in Python UnicodeDecodeError
I need to automate some requests but I need to use cookies from Goggle and some other sites. This code used to work just fine until some days:
import browser_cookie3
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
cookies = browser_cookie3.chrome()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookies)

but now I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 0: invalid start byte
I tried using http.cookiejar which works for POST but not for GET requests (just figured this out, will go deeper):
import http.cookiejar
import mechanicalsoup

cookies = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar('/Users/santiagofacchini/Downloads/cookies.txt')
cookies.load()

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookies)

# requests here

